Graphics.DrawString doesn't update text in OnPaint in Windows Forms C#
Sorry if I ask something simple. I asked in Discord and IRC and for two days nobody has provied a solution.
I have the following form:
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         base.OnPaint(e);
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
         Console.WriteLine($"OnPaint: {ClientRectangle}");
         e.Graphics.DrawString($"{ClientRectangle}", Font, Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);
     }
 }

When I run it, I see a black rectangle and a text above it with the coordinates.
However, when I'm resizing the form and I see a bunch of "OnPain: ..." messages (which indicates that my OnPaint is being called) the initial text never changes.
What is going on here really?
I uploaded my source code here: https://github.com/OnkelTem/CSharpDrawStringIssue
I also recorded two videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeRDKbGyxwU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzqtWy6flsk


What you see here is the default behavior.
Painting the background of a window is a costly procedure. It's done when the window is first rendered, then only if you ask for it.
Or when it becomes necessary, if the window needs to be restored (e.g., you minimize a top-level window, which also affects its child Controls).
To repaint a window, you usually call InvalidateRect or RedrawWindow (includes its child Controls), which map to the managed Invalidate() and Invalidate(true) method calls.
You have different managed tools to affect the behavior of a window:
you can override CreateParams to add / remove styles, call the SetStyle() method, override specific methods (e.g., OnLayout())
In this case, you're asking for the window to be repainted when its size changes.
When this becomes necessary (remembering that it is something that has a cost), you usually set the ResizeRedraw property in the constructor of a window:
// A Form, but can be another type of window
public SomeForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    ResizeRedraw = true;

    // Or, same thing, this is what happens under the hood when you set the property
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}

It's probably better to also enable enhanced double-buffering here:
public SomeForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    ResizeRedraw = true;
    DoubleBuffered = true;

    // Or
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}


You need to use the SetStyle() method, in Custom Controls, to set
the enhanced double-buffering feature, there's no property for that.

The state set by ResizeRedraw is tested in different conditions, for example when the window is resized, its padding is changed etc. The window is then repainted (invalidated) if ResizeRedraw = true.
OptimizedDoubleBuffer and ResizeRedraw are automatically set when there's a background Image with an Alpha channel

Thanks Jimi! What looks really strange to me is why the first function which fills the background works (it fills new regions during resize with black) while the second function doesn't. I guess there should be a way to see that filling also works partially, but not sure how to do it. Maybe change colors, dunno.

As mentioned, erasing the background of a window is a costly procedure. It's only done when explicitly requested. The normal operation, when WM_ERASEBKGND is received, is to mark the invalidated Region for erasing. How this is done, depends on different conditions. You can evaluate the difference if you set SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false); in the constructor, then paint the background in OnPaintBackground or OnPaint. See what the window's background color is here, and what happens when you resize the window. It should clarify why your string is not drawn when you expect it to

In short: The WM_PAINT message is only called when something triggered the update. So to update your control need this to trigger it:
// With or without the region to repaint.
this.Invalidate(new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50));
this.Update();

So this triggers it ones, so to continue update it, you need a Timer.
Like you commented, using the Resize is a good idea:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        Invalidate();
        Update();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
        Console.WriteLine($"OnPaint: {ClientRectangle}");
        e.Graphics.DrawString($"{ClientRectangle}", Font, Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);

    }
}


Could you please elaborat a little more? The black rectangle gets repaint allocating new area - i.e. the first function does its job. But not the second, DrawString. Why is that? And where should I really call Invalidate, in OnResize handler?

See the added example.

Don't call Update() explicitly to force an extraordinary and immediate repaint. If you need that, it's usually the sign of using some blocking code on the UI thread that chokes the message pump. So Invalidate() should be just enough: once the pending events are processed a regular WM_PAINT will occur to update your invalid regions.

@GyörgyKőszeg Yes, true, depends on if you want to force it or not.

Thanks folks! Calling some extra Invalidate in addition to what a code should do already - doesn't feel quite right to me. Have a look at the @Jimi's comment to my question. I believe that one is closer to the real solution of the problem, which was: DrawString() might not work if erm... configured incorrectly, kind of  :)
